# Setting JDBC Properties Using DataSource

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, datasource

I am connecting to a mysql database using the DataSource object.

```
DataSource mysql = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/MySQLDataSource");
Connection conn = mysql.getConnection();
```

I want to set the property

```
rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

for when I am doing some batch uploads. I have seen examples how to do this when people are using a driver manager like below:

```
String myConnectionString =
    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/mydb?" +
    "useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8" +
    "&rewriteBatchedStatements=true";
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(myConnectionString, "root", "whatever"))
```

How do I go about setting this property using the DataSource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by doing the following steps:

```
DataSource datasource = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/MySQLDataSource");
MysqlDataSource mysql_datasource = datasource.unwrap(MysqlDataSource.class);
mysql_datasource.setRewriteBatchedStatements(true);
Connection conn = mysql.getConnection();
```

Everything worked smoothly then. This extra unwrap() call was needed because I was attempting this on glassfish. Check the answer by aguibert below for further information.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @aguibert answer, you can configure the same at global level as well, by editing the `url` of your `Resource` name as below:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MySQLDataSource" auth="Container" 
               type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
               driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/mydb?rewriteBatchedStatements=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" 
               username="root" 
               password="root" 
               maxActive="100" 
               maxIdle="20" 
               maxWait="10000"/>
```

Comment: it looks like he's already figured out how to set props in the URL in the OP.  I think he was just wondering if there was a way to do this through java classes.  Also, this looks like your answer is XML format... is this Spring perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

If you cast your datasource to the specific implementation you're using, you will be able to use all the get/set methods specific to the jdbc driver you are using.

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource;
//...
MysqlDataSource mysql = (MysqlDataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/MySQLDataSource");
mysql.setRewriteBatchedStatements(true);
Connection conn = mysql.getConnection();
```

See this link for reference:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: Hey Aguibert, that compiled totally fine. However when I tried to run that example it ended up throwing the following run time error:  Severe: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.DataSource40 cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource     Any ideas what is going wrong here? Can't seem to find anything on this anywhere!

Comment: @TomO'Brien nothing is wrong here -- what's going on is it looks like you're using the Glassfish appserver, which will wrap the real mysql connection with it's own "managed connection wrapper" -- hence why when you call the unwrap() method, it gives you the underlying implementation object.  Since my response does answer the initial question you asked I would really appreciate it if you could mark my answer as the accepted answer (or at least give it an upvote).  Thanks!